# How to display hierarchy levels with text

Tags: tree, hierarchical-data

As the title says. It's a tree data structure that I need to display using only text.

--something
----like
----this
------but more visually
--------understandable

What is the de facto way to do this as used maybe by CLIs etc?

Answer (score 0):

There is a property on the TreeNode class called level. You could loop through all nodes and add a number of tab characters to the string for the node based on level. This would then indent your text according to the level of the node in the string.